# Parsing JSON / associative arrays in from Twitter API response in PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth, associative-array

I am using the Twitter API v.1.1 to retrieve tweets relating to certain hash-tags.

```
$tweets = $connection->get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$tweets = json_encode($tweets);

echo '<pre>';
    $objJson = json_decode($tweets, TRUE);
    print_r ($objJson);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Above is the code I am using to gather the response.

This is the response I get back

```
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                            [result_type] => recent
                            [iso_language_code] => en
                        )

                    [created_at] => Sun Aug 18 16:24:36 +0000 2013
                    [id] => 369132733080936448
                    [id_str] => 369132733080936448
                    [text] => Macy's Almeda, Houston, TX:  Retail Commission Sales Associa - http://t.co/iz3YdBBCzC #jobs #Macy's #Houston
                    [source] => Best Jobs Online
                    [truncated] => 
                    [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                    [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                    [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                    [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                    [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 237507695
                            [id_str] => 237507695
                            [name] => Best Jobs
                            [screen_name] => bestjobsonline
                            [location] => 
                            [description] => Best Jobs Online - we search the web for the best internships and jobs for you. No need to search yourself! Follow our stream and boost your career!
                            [url] => http://t.co/SkmHCpOnzM
                            [entities] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [url] => http://t.co/SkmHCpOnzM
                                                            [expanded_url] => http://www.internships2013.com
                                                            [display_url] => internships2013.com
                                                            [indices] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                    [1] => 22
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [description] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [protected] => 
                            [followers_count] => 6172
                            [friends_count] => 13
                            [listed_count] => 240
                            [created_at] => Thu Jan 13 00:36:32 +0000 2011
                            [favourites_count] => 0
                            [utc_offset] => -18000
                            [time_zone] => Central Time (US & Canada)
                            [geo_enabled] => 
                            [verified] => 
                            [statuses_count] => 847813
                            [lang] => en
                            [contributors_enabled] => 
                            [is_translator] => 
                            [profile_background_color] => 022330
                            [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                            [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                            [profile_background_tile] => 
                            [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1214148827/bjo_logo_normal.png
                            [profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1214148827/bjo_logo_normal.png
                            [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                            [profile_sidebar_border_color] => A8C7F7
                            [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => C0DFEC
                            [profile_text_color] => 333333
                            [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                            [default_profile] => 
                            [default_profile_image] => 
                            [following] => 
                            [follow_request_sent] => 
                            [notifications] => 
                        )

                    [geo] => 
                    [coordinates] => 
                    [place] => 
                    [contributors] => 
                    [retweet_count] => 0
                    [favorite_count] => 0
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [hashtags] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => jobs
                                            [indices] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 86
                                                    [1] => 91
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => Macy
                                            [indices] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 92
                                                    [1] => 97
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => Houston
                                            [indices] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 100
                                                    [1] => 108
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [symbols] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [urls] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => http://t.co/iz3YdBBCzC
                                            [expanded_url] => http://bit.ly/16UtroW
                                            [display_url] => bit.ly/16UtroW
                                            [indices] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 63
                                                    [1] => 85
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [user_mentions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [favorited] => 
                    [retweeted] => 
                    [possibly_sensitive] => 
                    [lang] => en
                )
```

How do I format this response to only show me the date and text of each of these Tweets. Thanks for the help. I'm a noob, and any help would come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

This loops through your statuses and adds the values of created_at and text to a new array.

```
$data = array();
foreach($objJson["statuses"] as $status) {
    $data[] = array(
        "created_at" => $status["created_at"],
        "text" => $status["text"]
    );
}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data,1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi there, 

Thanks for the help. I tried your code and now getting these error messages: "Trying to get property of non-object" & "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

This is my code currently:

'$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23macy");
$tweets = json_encode($tweets);
$obJson = json_decode($tweets, TRUE);
$data = array();
foreach($obJson->statuses as $status) {
    $data[] = array(
        "created_at" => $status->createdAt,
        "text" => $status->text
    );
}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data,1) . "</pre>";'

Comment: I changed my code a while ago because i first did not saw the TRUE in your json_decode which means that you do not want an object but an associative array. So try the newer code!